How can one be sure QGIS is 'Not Responding' vs 'its taking a very long time'?
How can one be sure QGIS is 'Not Responding' or whether 'its taking a very long time'?
This is a general question. I've noticed before that 'Not responding' can really mean 'be patient, its taking longer'.
I have devised a set of procedures that enable me to compile a 'cost raster' for Least Cost Path assessments for an area in Africa. The original DEM I used to test out my procedures in a small geographic area of Africa has a size of 60MB.
I now need to scale this up for a much larger geographic area whereby the original DEM is now 2.6GB 
While carrying out one of the tasks using GRASS r.stream.extract I'm trying to assess whether the task is simply not working because my 2.6GB file is too large, or whether it is very large and therefore requires more time? I've already run it for 16 hours.
The Windows Task Manager seems to suggest that GRASS is working away....but that QGIS is 'Not Responding'. Conflicting messages??

How are you running your processing? As far as I know, "not responding" means that the main GUI thread (a thread is a special kind of program that gets scheduled by the computers operating system) does not get scheduled enough to timely respond to operating system "pings" (for e.g. mouse movenent) because it is busy with your processing. So it really matters how you call your grass function. From a script or from the GUI?

I run GRASS from the GUI.

It seems that QGIS was in fact taking a long time.
The suggestions in this post were valuable in helping me successfully complete my task. Increasing the 'Maximum Memory To Be Used' had a huge impact.
